# Convert user input tp MYSQL TIME literal

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date, time

For the following code to work you have to use the proper time literal.

```
(SELECT ADDTIME('09:00', 003000))
```

So 30 minutes must be 003000 and 1 hour must be 010000.

The value of the interval will be user entered in the form of minutes (30, 60, 90, etc).

The question is how to efficiently convert these values to the proper literal within a stored procedure.

Comment: You can divide by 60 then modulus 60

Comment: Why use those formats and not simply convert to  `30:00`, `60:00` and `1:30:00` like you should when you use `ADDTIME(..)` function.

Comment: Sorry I am not quite so proficient yet. Can you provide and example: _DUR = ...........

Comment: Something like   `SELECT ADDTIME('09:00' , SEC_TO_TIME((90) * 60));`  where 90 is your input in minutes the 60 is there to convert minutes into seconds which `SEC_TO_TIME` needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a time expression from the number of minutes given as input with [`SEC_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) (that accepts a number of seconds), and then pass it as the second argument to [`ADDTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) :

```
ADDTIME('09:00', SEC_TO_TIME(@minutes * 60))
```

Comment: "ADDTIME also accepts a number of seconds a second argument" No it doesn't second param of ADDTIME function requires a TIME datatype not a INT datatype using `SEC_TO_TIME()` is required here... "ADDTIME(expr1,**expr2**) adds expr2 to expr1 and returns the result. expr1 is a time or datetime expression, and **expr2 is a time expression**" source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime   ... using INT as datatype will cause invalid calculation see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ohg6FtpzgrLwTq4VStE7T7/3)

Comment: @RaymondNijland : you are absolutely right, thanks for the rectification and for the demo. I updated my answer accordingly...